# From timestamp to DateFormat "Wed Jul 17 05:33:07 UTC 2013"

Tags: java, datetime, timestamp

In java i am trying to convert timestamp to date for the specified format I can achieve like this only

```
 DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss yyyy");
    Date date = format.parse("022310141505");
    System.out.println(date);
```

How do i add 'UTC'  in the date format `"Wed Jul 17 05:33:07 UTC 2013"` ?

it throws error

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "022310141505"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:337)
```

Comment: You're passing `022310141505` to a DateFormat expecting a string in the format `EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss yyyy`. How could that possibly work? Please rephrase your question, tell us the input you have, and the output you want.

Comment: What is `022310141505` anyway? Seems too short to be in milliseconds, and it's not in any obvious date or time format.

Comment: @MarkM this is timestamp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy ");
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    Date date = new Date();
    System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
```

In additionally try some thing as follows

```
    DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy ");
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMddyyHHmmss");
    Date date = format.parse("022310141505");
    System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear but in your code, you are trying to "parse" the date, that means that you are trying to go from a string representation back to a Date object. I guess what you want to do is to "format" the date, that is going from a Date object to a string representation.

First you have to convert your timestamp to a Date

```
Date d = new Date(22310141505)
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss yyyy");
System.out.println(formatter.format(d));
```

A comment about the way you are trying to parse the date. You are actually trying to parse a general string (that happens to look like a timestamp) but it totally doesn't match the pattern that you constructed the `DateFormat` with.

Answer (score 0):

If the number above is a timestamp, simply turn it into a date first.

```
long time = 022310141505L;
Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(time);
Date date = ts.getTime();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss yyyy");
System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
```

Comment: ` Date date = ts.getTime();` returns long but it is date

Comment: SimpleDateFormat formats it. Now that I think about it, `022310141505` fits with the `MMddyyHHmmss` format. Are you sure it isn't this?

Comment: yes Mark. when i tried `long timestamp = 1374044812 * 1000;  // msec
        java.util.Date d = new java.util.Date(timestamp);
        System.out.println(d);` it shows `Sun Dec 28 05:44:37 IST 1969` but the timestamp is todays date

Comment: @jackyesind: `long timestamp = 1374044812L * 1000L;`. Otherwise, you'll have integer multiplication, and an integer overflow.